# I need to return a String but only have an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, kendo-ui-angular2

Another Observable question.

I'm working with angular translation service and Kendo.UI components.

According to the Kendo.UI [documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/localization/messages/#toc-using-the-message-service), I can implement a MessageService to translate its components.

To do so, I have to extend an abstract class that contains a method that return a string:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyMessageService extends MessageService {

  private messages = {'kendo.upload.select': 'initial value'}

  constructor(private readonly translate: TranslateService) {
    super();

    this.translate.get('my_translation_key')
    .subscribe((value) => {
      this.messages['kendo.upload.select'] = value;
    });
  }

  public get(key: string): string {
    return this.messages[key];
  }
}
```

The problem is, the moment kendo injects my custom service, the observables were not resolved yet and my button never get its value changed from "'initial value'" to the translated.

From my understatement, kendo's service should accept an observable, not a string. But I'm not very familiar with promises/subjects/observables.

Is there a workaround for this?

ps.: I know TranslateService has a .instant(key) method, but the same way, the values are not loaded yet.

Comment: Have a look at the this discussion: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/362

Comment: This is close of what I need. Should have be more specific in the question, but I really thought that was a way to "await" the observable. Thank you

Comment: Well, if you are working with the angular `router`, you could use a resolver (`Resolve`) to wait with loading the route until the translations are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are saying it the observable is pushed before kendo subscribes. If that is the case then you should use a ReplaySubject instead of an Observable as the Replaysubject will push all the values that were given to the observable to the subscriber when it subscribes.You can tell it how many observed values to replay.

Also you could try instead to call your server after view init or even OnInint. Calling the service in the constructor is not recommended as the view is not done rendering and any html async pipes may not be set yet. Worst case you can use the Replay subject.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just got this task back. The problem is that kendo does not subscribe at all. It only accept a string. And here is the reason: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/362